Chromecast HLS Casting Issue: Cause 'session_error'
I'm encountering an issue when attempting to cast an HLS file to my Chromecast. Some HLS files works fine (e.g., https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8), attempting to cast others HLS files results in a "session_error" message. This occurs both when using a website like https://smm76.github.io/react-castjs/ and when developing my own application using the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jdion/cast-react.
What I've Tried: I tested casting using various HLS files, such as:

https://storage.googleapis.com/shaka-demo-assets/angel-one-widevine-hls/hls.m3u8
https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8

However, each attempt with these files resulted in the "session_error" message.
